# How to analyze if the email is registered using the python requests without rendering the html?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am making a code in python that analyzes if email already is registered in the following site: https://www.infojobs.com.br/RememberPass.aspx

For the forgotten password it is possible to do because the site shows when the email does not exist, if email is wrong. But analyze this process with the python requests.

```
 import requests
    import json

    headers = {
    'authority': 'www.infojobs.com.br',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.80 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
}

    data = {
    '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': 'D4C35ECA',
    'cRemPassEmailCompany$txtEmail':'' ,
    'cRemPassEmailCompany$txtCPNJ':'' ,
    'cRemPassCandidate$txtEmail': 'daviluis400@gmail.com',
    'cRemPassCandidate$btnStep1': 'Enviar',
    'cRemPassCandidate$txtCPF':'',
    'cRemPassCandidate$rbtlstSend': '1',
}

     response = requests.post('https://www.infojobs.com.br/RememberPass.aspx', 
     headers=headers,data=data)
    response2 = json.loads(response.text)
```

I wanted to check email without rendering html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load full form and remove you don't need. Note: What i said is so simple because this job doesn't contain any tricks. What you need to do is compare with the browser request content again and again, then find out the necessary columns.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'Origin': 'www.infojobs.com.br',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.80 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    "Referer": "https://www.infojobs.com.br/RememberPass.aspx",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}

def Candidatos(email,data):
    data["cRemPassCandidate$txtEmail"]  = email
    data["cRemPassCandidate$rbtlstSend"] = "1"

    del data["cRemPassCandidate$btnStep2"]
    del data["cRemPassEmailCompany$btnEmailCompany"]

    return data

def Empresas(email,CNPJ,data):
    data["cRemPassEmailCompany$txtEmail"] = email
    data["cRemPassEmailCompany$txtCPNJ"] = CNPJ
    data["cRemPassCandidate$rbtlstSend"] = "1"

    del data["cRemPassCandidate$btnStep2"]
    del data["cRemPassCandidate$btnStep1"]

    return data


with requests.Session() as s:
    s.verify = False
    s.headers = headers
    url = 'https://www.infojobs.com.br/RememberPass.aspx'

    response = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,"lxml")
    data = {ele.get("name"):ele.get("value") if ele.get("value") else "" for ele in soup.find_all("input")}
    data = Candidatos(email="k@outlook.com",data=data)
    resp = s.post(url,data)

    assert "Infelizmente não temos o seu e-mail. Clique no link abaixo e tente novamente.".encode() in resp.content

    response = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,"lxml")
    data = {ele.get("name"):ele.get("value") if ele.get("value") else "" for ele in soup.find_all("input")}
    data = Empresas(email="k@outlook.com",CNPJ="123",data=data)
    resp = s.post(url,data)

    assert "nenhuma empresa cadastrada com estes dados em nossa base de dados".encode() in resp.content
```

Comment: It is possible to use this technique or similar for scraping of sites that do not use asp.net?

Comment: yes. The basic requirement of every website is to allow users to access it with a browser. That means if they do not add incredible protection, you can use this way to solve most of problems. @DaviLuis

Comment: Extra mention: If they use JavaScript you can use requests_html. For cloudflare, use cfscrape. But few websites will use some technique to verify whether you are using a real browser(they even can know if you are using selenium driver).  @DaviLuis

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python requests to do this only if the page that you are trying to view is server-rendered. Otherwise, the page displays messages by running JavaScript code. You must run this JavaScript code to get the message. If you're looking to do this, I recommend you use [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/)